# Copy multiples files into single file using VBA

Tags: vba, vbscript

i am trying to write a code in a form application where i can select multiples files and append the data of all the selected files into the another file (master file).

below i wrote one function which invokes on clicking of the Userform button.

while running this code i am getting Automation Error -2147221080 (800401a8)

while debugging i found that its giving error during re-assigning the value in below line of code

Set rngData = shtData.UsedRange

could someone please help me to solve this issue, i am new to VBA and not getting the cause of the error.

```
Function copyfiles()
Dim wbkMaster As Workbook
Dim shtMaster As Worksheet
Dim rngMaster As Range
Dim wbkData As Workbook
Dim shtData As Worksheet
Dim rngData As Range
Dim intChoice As Integer
Dim strPath As String
Dim strPath1 As String
 Dim array1() As String
 Dim filepath As String
 Dim count As Integer
 Dim i As Integer

'to select master file

 Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
 intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
 If intChoice <> 0 Then
 strPath = Application.FileDialog( _
 msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
 End If

Set wbkMaster = Workbooks.Open(strPath)
Set shtMaster = wbkMaster.Worksheets(1)



 'to select source file(s)
  Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = True

  intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

  If intChoice <> 0 Then
  For i = 1 To Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen _
 ).SelectedItems.count
 strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen _
 ).SelectedItems(i)
 filepath = filepath & strPath & ","
 Next i
 End If

 array1 = Split(filepath, ",", -1, vbBinaryCompare)
 count = i - 1
 Set rngMaster = shtMaster.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
 For j = 0 To count - 1

 Set wbkData = Workbooks.Open(array1(j))
 Set shtData = wbkData.Worksheets(1)
 Set wbkMaster = Workbooks.Open(strPath)
 Set shtMaster = wbkMaster.Worksheets(1)
 Set rngData = shtData.UsedRange

 ' copy data across
 rngData.Copy rngMaster

 ' simply close data
 wbkData.Close False

 '  release objects
Set rngData = Nothing
Set shtData = Nothing
Set wbkData = Nothing

wbkMaster.Close True

Set shtMaster = Nothing

Set wbkMaster = Nothing

Next

   Set rngMaster = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Opening and closing the master workbook inside the loop is not a good approach and might be the source of head aches. Try opening once before the loop on the data files, then save/close after the loop.

Comment: if i am opening the files once before the loop and saving after the loop then its not saving all files content, its saving only content of  last file.

Comment: Ok, in the new code, try replacing `Set shtMaster = wbkMaster.Worksheets(1)` with `Set shtMaster = wbkMaster.Worksheets.Add`

Comment: @A.S.H: thank you so much, your suggestion worked after changes of 2-3 more lines :).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try Ron deBruin's code.

```
Sub Basic_Example_1()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next

                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:C1")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub

Function RDB_Last(choice As Integer, rng As Range)
'Ron de Bruin, 5 May 2008
' 1 = last row
' 2 = last column
' 3 = last cell
    Dim lrw As Long
    Dim lcol As Integer

    Select Case choice

    Case 1:
        On Error Resume Next
        RDB_Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                            after:=rng.cells(1), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 2:
        On Error Resume Next
        RDB_Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                            after:=rng.cells(1), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 3:
        On Error Resume Next
        lrw = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                       after:=rng.cells(1), _
                       Lookat:=xlPart, _
                       LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                       MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        lcol = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        after:=rng.cells(1), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        RDB_Last = rng.Parent.cells(lrw, lcol).Address(False, False)
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            RDB_Last = rng.cells(1).Address(False, False)
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

    End Select
```

End Function

From, here.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win008.htm

Also, try this AddIn.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm